# Summing Distinct Rows

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I am trying to get a total Sum per part, but for some reason it is not giving me a distinct sum with this code.  It is repeating the same part number based on number of records in the subquery.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Select Distinct IIF(x.omlPartID in ('10027','10028')
    ,x.omlPartID
    ,x.jmaPartID) as PartID
    , Sum(Cast(Total_Quantity as INT)) as SumTot
From (
    SELECT distinct SalesOrderLines.omlsalesorderID
        , salesorderlines.omlSalesOrderLineID
        , SalesOrderLines.omlPartID
        , JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaPartID
        ,  (
            IIF(rtrim(SalesOrderLines.omlPartID) in ('10027','10028')
            , 1
            , JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2.jmaQuantityPerParent
            ) * SalesOrderLines.omlOrderQuantity
            ) As 'Total_Quantity'
    FROM M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrderLines SalesOrderLines 
    Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks SalesOrderJobLinks 
        On SalesOrderLines.omlSalesOrderID = SalesOrderJobLinks.omjSalesOrderID 
            AND SalesOrderlines.omlSalesOrderLineID = SalesOrderJobLinks.omjSalesOrderLineID 
    Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.Jobs Jobs 
        on SalesOrderJobLinks.omjJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID 
    Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 
        On Jobs.jmpJobID = JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2. jmaJobID 
    Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrders SalesOrders 
        On SalesOrderLines.omlSalesOrderID = SalesOrders.ompSalesOrderID 
    Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.Organizations Organizations 
        On SalesOrders.ompCustomerOrganizationID = Organizations.cmoOrganizationID 
    WHERE JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaPartID in ('10027','10028') 
        or (
            SalesOrderLines.omlPartID in ('10027','10028') 
            and 
            JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaPartID is Null
            )
) x
Group by x.omlPartID, x.jmaPartID
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  ,, your actual result and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Learn to use table alias.

Comment: How do you expect people to help you if all you give is a broken, unreadable query???  Start by telling what you want to accomplish.  Provide sample input, expected output, table relationship.  Then maybe, people will help you.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `iif` in standard SQL). Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems  you need  group by PartID

```
  Select IIF(x.omlPartID in ('10027','10028'),x.omlPartID,x.jmaPartID) as PartID, Sum(Cast(Total_Quantity as INT)) as SumTot
  From (SELECT distinct SalesOrderLines.omlsalesorderID, salesorderlines.omlSalesOrderLineID, SalesOrderLines.omlPartID, JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaPartID, (IIF(rtrim(SalesOrderLines.omlPartID) in ('10027','10028'),1,JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2.jmaQuantityPerParent)*SalesOrderLines.omlOrderQuantity) As 'Total_Quantity'
  FROM M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrderLines SalesOrderLines 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks SalesOrderJobLinks On SalesOrderLines.omlSalesOrderID = SalesOrderJobLinks.omjSalesOrderID AND SalesOrderlines.omlSalesOrderLineID = SalesOrderJobLinks.omjSalesOrderLineID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.Jobs Jobs on SalesOrderJobLinks.omjJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 On Jobs.jmpJobID = JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaJobID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrders SalesOrders On SalesOrderLines.omlSalesOrderID = SalesOrders.ompSalesOrderID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.Organizations Organizations On SalesOrders.ompCustomerOrganizationID = Organizations.cmoOrganizationID 
  WHERE JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaPartID in ('10027','10028') or (SalesOrderLines.omlPartID in ('10027','10028') and JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 .jmaPartID is Null)) x
  Group by IIF(x.omlPartID in ('10027','10028'),x.omlPartID,x.jmaPartID)
```

and you could use alias table name for reduce text eg

```
  Select IIF(x.omlPartID in ('10027','10028'),x.omlPartID,x.jmaPartID) as PartID
  , Sum(Cast(Total_Quantity as INT)) as SumTot
  From (SELECT distinct sol.omlsalesorderID, salesorderlines.omlSalesOrderLineID
    , sol.omlPartID, jamc2.jmaPartID, (IIF(rtrim(sol.omlPartID) 
        in ('10027','10028')
    ,1,jamc2jmaQuantityPerParent)*sol.omlOrderQuantity) As 'Total_Quantity'
  FROM M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrderLines sol 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks sollink On sol.omlSalesOrderID = sollink.omjSalesOrderID 
        AND SalesOrderlines.omlSalesOrderLineID = sollink.omjSalesOrderLineID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.Jobs Jobs on sollink.omjJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.JobAssemblyMaterialCombo2 jamc2 On Jobs.jmpJobID = jamc2.jmaJobID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.SalesOrders so On sol.omlSalesOrderID = so.ompSalesOrderID 
  Left Outer Join M1_HB.dbo.Organizations org On so.ompCustomerOrganizationID = org.cmoOrganizationID 
  WHERE jamc2.jmaPartID in ('10027','10028') or (sol.omlPartID in ('10027','10028') and jamc2.jmaPartID is Null)) x
  Group by IIF(x.omlPartID in ('10027','10028'),x.omlPartID,x.jmaPartID)
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge,  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi scaisEdge,   I am running the query on SQL Server Management Studio 2017.  It's telling my that "Part ID" is not a valid column and highlighting the "Group By PartID".   When I change it back to "Group by x.omlPartID, x.jmaPartID', it returns the same result I had originally.  I am not get distinct PartID vs Sum records.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you so much for your kind help.